# how can i use curl -X POST api using php https://www.fembed.com/api#download-video

Tags: php, curl

I Am Trying To use this api from https://www.fembed.com/api#transfer-video can some one please give a full exaple of how to use it using php, i dot know how to use curl -X POST.

````
-d "client_id=ClIENT_ID&client_secret=ClIENT_SECRET"
-d "links=JSON_ENCODED_ARRAY"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"```

can someone help me and give me an example please
````

Answer (score 2):

You have to set using php-curl

[php-curl-manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Here is parameters:

[curl parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

With your data do this curl:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url-to-send-post'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"client_id=ClIENT_ID&client_secret=ClIENT_SECRET&file_id=IdOfVideo&title=NEW_TITLE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($data);//response data
```

Comment: can you help me how to use this api using php https://www.fembed.com/api#download-video

Comment: client_id is not urlencoded, client_secret is not url-encoded, file_id is not urlencoded, title is not urlencoded, do it properly: http://paste.debian.net/plain/1089449   (without proper urlencoding, the code will malfunction if the title contains special characters like `&` or `=`)

Comment: Can you give me an example from the site https://www.fembed.com/api#download-video please

Answer (score 0):

`-X` is `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` (but when using POST in particular, don't use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, use `CURLOPT_POST` instead) and `-d` is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and `-H` is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, as for examples, see the curl_setopt() documentation page at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: can you help me how to use this api using php fembed.com/api#download-video

Comment: @hihey in what way? which part of that api do you need help with?

Comment: curl -X POST https://www.fembed.com/api/download
-d "client_id=ClIENT_ID&client_secret=ClIENT_SECRET"
-d "links=JSON_ENCODED_ARRAY"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"                                                      Here how can i use it using php